# Why it runs into endless loop after I set rowKey to Math.random in rc-table?

Tags: reactjs

Can I use `Math.random` for the `rowKey` in `rc-table`?
Why it runs into endless loop after I update my component if I set the `rowKey` to `Math.random`?

```
import React from 'react';
import RcTable from 'rc-table';

class Folder extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            update: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var id = setInterval(() => {
            clearInterval(id);
            this.setState({
                update: !this.state.update,
            });
        }, 4000);
    }


    renderTable() {
        const columns = [
            {
                title: 'name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                key: 'name',
                width: 280,
            },
        ];

        const data = [
            {
                name: '12',
                id: 1,
            },
            {
                name: '123',
                id: 2,
            },
            {
                name: '1245',
                id: 3,
            },
            {
                name: '12345',
                id: 4,
            },
        ];

        return <RcTable data={data} columns={columns} rowKey={() => Math.random()} />
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderTable()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Folder;
```

At first, it runs ok. But when I update my component, an error called `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` will be thrown.

If I change the `rowKey` to `id`, everything is ok.

Why it will cause endless updating loop ?

Comment: I think its because of the floating value returned by Math.Random(), can you try with an integer key

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://github.com/react-component/table)

> rowKey
>
> string or Function(record):string
>
> 'key'
>
> If rowKey is string, `record[rowKey]` will be used as key. If rowKey
>   is function, the return value of `rowKey(record)` will be use as key.

So in your component you can't use any `Random Number`

```
rowKey={() => Math.random()}
```

Which is a function and not returning anything except `void`.

The `rowKey` must be valid `key` used by the `table`.

This might be a reason for your `Stack error`